# Unit testing: How to check if generated javascript (string) is valid javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

For unit testing purposes: Im searching for testing framework like NUnit that can validate if a "javascript" is valid within the most common browsers (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari). The javascript will be automaticly created from an class.

Does someone know if there is a testing framework like NUnit for this, within cscharp (c#)?
Ofcourse Im writing tests myself on the javascript so it should be good.

But I just want to be absolutly sure its valid.

Comment: unless your writing an X to JS compiler, generating JavaScript seems like a bad thing to do.

Comment: How complex is the generated javascript? What kind of verification do you need (apart from valid syntax)?

Comment: Its for an html helper, only the valid syntax should be fine.

Comment: @Raynos, why would it be a bad thing? See [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/JavaScriptIsAssemblyLanguageForTheWebSematicMarkupIsDeadCleanVsMachinecodedHTML.aspx) by Scott Hanselman

Comment: @ThomasLevesque as mentioned writing a full compiler to create this JS  is valid. However using string concatenation, templates or some other naive method to generate JS is bad.

Comment: I just want to validate the syntax, not compile the whole javascript. Just like resharper does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks useful: http://madskristensen.net/post/Verify-JavaScript-syntax-using-C.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Get a modified copy of [jshint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint) and run your generated code through to check whether it's correct. I'd probably use JS.NET 2010 for this or ironJS.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Selenium to actually run the Javascript in the supported browsers. It is easily used from any xUnit type testing framework and it supported by C#.